# Ошибка Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '='

Tags: php

Вот код

```
$a = rand(1,3);
$b = rand(1,3);
echo "<img src="\"http://geographi-krd.ru.purple.intobservatory.ru/" . $a . ".jpg\">";
echo "     ";
echo "<img src="\"http://geographi-krd.ru.purple.intobservatory.ru/" . $b . ".jpg\">";
```

Исправьте ошибку тут пишет

> `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=' in Z:\home\test1.ru\www\Battle.php on line 2`

кто поможет ставлю верно, плюс и 40 рейтинга

Comment: @Семен Форматируйте код, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
   echo '<img src="http://geographi-krd.ru.purple.intobservatory.ru/'.$a. '.jpg"> ';
   echo '<img src="http://geographi-krd.ru.purple.intobservatory.ru/'.$b. '.jpg">';
```

Навернок так

Comment: и кстати не надо бросаться словами на счет рейтинга и плюсов....

Answer (score 0):

```
src="\"
```

Поменяйте на

```
src=\"
```

Вам даже подсветка на Хешкоде помогает).

Answer (score 0):

Надеюсь, будет не лишним, на будущее :

```
<?php
echo 'text ololo';//верно
echo "text ololo";//тоже верно
#
echo "<a href="?load">link!</a>";//не верно, т.к. выражение содержится в двойных кавычках (") и компилятор будет выводить то, что написано от первой " и до второй " - ("<a href="), а дальше ошибка синтаксическая (?load">link!</a>";).
echo "<a href=\"?load\">link!</a>";//теперь правильно, т.к. есть открывающая двойная и закрывающая двойная кавычки, а остальные двойные кавычки экранированы т.к. являются текстом, а не фрагментом кода.
echo '<a href="?load">link!</a>';//так тоже правильно, т.к. используются одиночные кавычки в качестве открывающей и закрывающей.
echo '<a href='?load'>link!</a>';//а вот так опять будет ошибка, исправим на :
echo '<a href=\'?load\'>link!</a>';//теперь правильно, кавычки, которые должны быть текстом - экранированы
echo "<a href='?load'>link!</a>";//тоже правильно
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Я бы написал так:

```
<?php
$a = rand(1,3);
$b = rand(1,3);
?>
<img src="http://geographi-krd.ru.purple.intobservatory.ru/<?=$a?>.jpg">
<img src="http://geographi-krd.ru.purple.intobservatory.ru/<?=$b?>.jpg">
```

Так намного приятнее и меньше кода и главное - понятнее.
Кстати совсем необязательно ставить много пробелов между тэгами, один перенос строки заменит пробел, а любой браузер их все равно объединит в один.